# Magento Promotions - Buy a selection of products for a fixed price

Tags: magento, promotions

I'm having trouble with setting up a promotion.

The aim is to offer any 2 products for a fixed price. Eg, buy any 2 cakes for £5 (instead of £7 total, or £3.50 each - a £2 saving). There can be several SKU's to choose from, all under the same offer. The easy part is they are all the same price. The rule will *not* apply to all products within 1 category, just some of them.

I'm also trying to do the same as above but with 3 or 4 products

I've tried doing it several ways but it's never quite right. As soon as you add other unrelated SKU's to the basket the pricing doesn't work as I want!

Any help will be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking Magento directly, they have advised me that this is not possible natively. The only solution is to add an extension.